# unit testing umbraco 7.12 controller

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, umbraco, umbraco7

i've setup a unit test project for my umbraco 7.12 installation with Our.Umbraco.Community.Tests nuget installed as well as nunit, nunit 3 test adapter and NUnitV2Driver. i have a unit test where i'm inheriting from BaseRoutingTest (from the umbraco community tests nuget) that nunit just doesn't seem to want to run:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Security;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Configuration;
using Umbraco.Core.Dictionary;
using Umbraco.Core.Logging;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Core.Profiling;
using Umbraco.Tests.TestHelpers;
using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Web.Security;
using umbraco7._12test.Models;
using Assert = NUnit.Framework.Assert;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest1:BaseRoutingTest
    {
        protected UmbracoContext UmbracoContext { get; set; }
    protected UmbracoHelper UmbracoHelper { get; set; }

    protected IPublishedContent Content { get; set; }

    protected RouteData RouteData { get; set; }

    [SetUp]
    public override void Initialize()
    {

        base.Initialize();

        SettingsForTests.ConfigureSettings(SettingsForTests.GenerateMockSettings());

        this.RouteData = new RouteData();
        var routingContext = this.GetRoutingContext(
            "http://localhost",
            -1,
            this.RouteData,
            true,
            UmbracoConfig.For.UmbracoSettings());

        this.UmbracoContext = routingContext.UmbracoContext;

        this.Content = Mock.Of<IPublishedContent>();


        this.UmbracoContext.PublishedContentRequest = new Umbraco.Web.Routing.PublishedContentRequest(
            new Uri("http://localhost"),
            routingContext,
            UmbracoConfig.For.UmbracoSettings().WebRouting,
            s => new string[0])
        {
            PublishedContent = this.Content,
            Culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB")
        };


        var routeDefinition = new RouteDefinition
        {
            PublishedContentRequest = this.UmbracoContext.PublishedContentRequest
        };

        this.RouteData.DataTokens.Add(Constants.Web.UmbracoRouteDefinitionDataToken, routeDefinition);

        this.UmbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(
          this.UmbracoContext,
          this.Content,
          Mock.Of<ITypedPublishedContentQuery>(),
          Mock.Of<IDynamicPublishedContentQuery>(),
          Mock.Of<ITagQuery>(),
          this.ApplicationContext.Services.DataTypeService,
          this.UmbracoContext.UrlProvider,
          new Mock<ICultureDictionary>().Object,
          Mock.Of<IUmbracoComponentRenderer>(),
          new MembershipHelper(this.UmbracoContext, Mock.Of<MembershipProvider>(), Mock.Of<RoleProvider>()));
    }

    [TearDown]
    public override void TearDown()
    {

        this.UmbracoHelper = null;
        this.UmbracoContext = null;
        this.Content = null;


        base.TearDown();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var apiController = new 
            umbraco7._12test.Controllers.ApiController(this.UmbracoContext,this.UmbracoHelper);
        var result = apiController.EditContact();
        var model = (ContactModel)result.Model;

        NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsNotNull(model.FirstName);
        NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsNotNull(model.LastName);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestMethod2() {
        Assert.AreEqual(1,1);
    }
}
}
```

as soon as i inherit from BaseRoutingTest nunit will no longer run my tests, no errors just a message saying there are no tests found -

```
[01/10/2018 14:56:32 Informational] NUnit couldn't find any tests in C:\project\umbraco7.12test\UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll
[01/10/2018 14:56:32 Informational] NUnit Adapter 3.10.0.21: Test execution complete
[01/10/2018 14:56:32 Warning] No test matches the given testcase filter `FullyQualifiedName=UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1` in C:\project\umbraco7.12test\UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll
```

if i don't inherit from BaseRoutingTest nunit will run tests again. i need to inherit from BaseRoutingTest though, to setup the UmbracoContext and other things that need to be mocked.
does anybody know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Umbraco, so I'm answering this from an NUnit perspective only...

You are trying to use the NUnit 3 test adapter to run NUnit V2 tests. You have installed the V2 driver in order to make NUnit 3 run NUnit V2 tests. Right?

Thing is, the NUnit 3 test adapter doesn't support use of extensions. Even if it did, you would have to copy those extensions manually to the location of the adapter and probably also manually edit a `.addins` file to make it work.

Much simpler is to use the original NUnit Test Adapter, which is for use with V2.

Comment: i've just tried this and no luck. thanks for the suggestion though, Charlie

Comment: Tried using the original NUnit V2 adapter you mean? That code has been stable for a long time, so I'm surprised.

Comment: yes i tried the original nunit v2 adapter. it must be something to do with my setup....